# Iterate the lines in a text file

Tags: php

[image: This is my file]

I want to read the text file line by line using php while copying only these values 1.23 , 0.5 , -1.8903, 186 , -0095

I will use `strtok()` to extract the part of each line I want.

I need help writing the code to iterate through each line.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: show your code and expected output

Answer (score 0):

*While you read the file* you can explode the file into an array of lines, then split by space and get the first element, like :

```
$text = "00123123      asdjasdjjdaswd
-32423     asdasda sdsagfgasdf
42     adklsdfkasdfsdf";

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $text); # EOL = End of line
foreach($lines as $line){
    $array = explode(" ", $line);
    echo $value = $array[0];
    echo "\n";
}

/* Outputs:
 00123123 
 -32423 
 42

*/
```

Alternatively you could write a regex that will get you the contents before the first whitespace per line.

Answer (score 0):

I have used given code:-

```
$file="test.txt";
$linecount = 0;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
while(!feof($handle)){
$line = fgets($handle);
$array = explode(" ", $line);
echo $value = $array[0];
 echo "\n";
$linecount++;

}

fclose($handle);
```